# $p$ prime, $P = \left\{ \frac{m}{p^e} \middle| m, e\in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$. Prove that $\mbox{Ext}(P; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{(p)}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, abelian-groups, p-adic-number-theory

I don't know why the book Homology by Saunders Mac Lane is wwaaayyy tttoooo hard to digest. :(((

This is like the third time I read this book, but still not clear is everything, and to tell the truth, I cannot even see (or see little) connections between the exercises and the information provided in each lesson.

It's exercise 7, on page 76 of the book. The current lesson is about **The obstructions to the extension of homomorphisms**. Ok, here's what it says:

## Problem

> Let $p$ be any prime, and define the set $P$ as follow: $P = \left\{ \frac{m}{p^e} \middle| m, e\in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$, clearly it's a subgroup of the additive Abelian group $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\mathbb{Z}^{(p)}$ be the additive group of $p-$adic integers. Prove that:
>
> $$\mbox{Ext}(P; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{(p)}/\mathbb{Z}$$

Ok, I know some strategies when doing problems on Ext is to find a ses with projective, or injective modules, then just kind of applying $\mbox{Ext}(-; A)$, and $\mbox{Ext}(A; -)$ to arrive at the les, and work from there.

Here's what I have tried, not much though. :(

- I've found the ses for $\mathbb{Z}^{(p)}$, i.e:
  $$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}^{(p)} \to \mathbb{Z}^{(p)} / \mathbb{Z} \to 0$$

  The problem is, if I work with that ses, then I have to apply $\mbox{Ext}(P; -)$ to the sequence. But there is no injective $\mathbb{Z}-$module there, so there's nothing that can make $\mbox{Ext}(P; \mbox{something injective}) = 0$.
- I also try to find a ses for $P$, but its definition confuses me. I know that every module $M$ can be embedded in $0 \to S \to F \to M \to 0$ for some projective $F$, but how should I use the definition of $P$ to find a 'good' ses like that?

I think I'm not seeing something here, or maybe I'm going on the wrong track. So any hints would be great. :*

Thank you very much,

And have a good day,

Comment: Do you mean "addictive" or "additive?"

Comment: Haha, I mean additive. Now I know why I felt a lilttle bit 'strange' when typing that word. :)) I'm sorry for that stupid mistake. I don't know how I got confused between those 2 words. I'm a foreigner though. :(

Comment: I never noticed before that additive and addictive were only one letter apart :)

Comment: @user49685: See also my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4516598).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$
Denote $P$ by $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]$, which is common practice indicating that it is the localization of $\mathbb{Z}$ at powers of $p$. Denote $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]/\mathbb{Z}$ by $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}$. We have an exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}\rightarrow 0$. Applying $\mathrm{Ext}(-,\mathbb{Z})$, part of the associated long exact sequence reads $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}],\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty},\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}],\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$, which turns out to be $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty},\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}],\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow 0$.

It remains to calculate $\mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty},\mathbb{Z})$. Taking the injective presentation of $\mathbb{Z}$: $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow 0$. Taking $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty},-)$, it becomes $0\rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty},\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty},\mathbb{Q})\rightarrow \mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$. Note that $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty},\mathbb{Q})=0$ since every element of $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}$ has torsion. Furthermore, $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is determined the images $e_i$ of $1/p^i$ respectively ($i\ge 0$), satisfying $pe_i=e_{i-1}$ ($i\ge1$). It is not hard to see that they are exactly $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the $p$-adic integers. So $\mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty},\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Let's analyze more closely. Take the exact sequence of chain complexes inducing the long exact sequence (some 0 omitted for simplicity):

$$\begin{CD}
0 @>0>> \mathbb{Z} @>\text{id}>>\mathbb{Z} \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
\bigoplus_{i \ge j > 0}\mathbb{Z} @>{e_{ij}\rightarrow (p^j e_i-e_{i-j})}>> \bigoplus_{i \ge 0}\mathbb{Z} @>{e_i \to \frac{1}{p^i}}>> \mathbb{Z} \left[\frac{1}{p} \right] \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
\bigoplus_{i \ge j > 0}\mathbb{Z} @>{e_{ij}\rightarrow (p^j e_i-e_{i-j}), (e_0 = 0)}>> \bigoplus_{i > 0}\mathbb{Z} @>{e_i \to \frac{1}{p^i}}>> \mathbb{Z} /p^\infty
\end{CD}
$$

Dualizing it renders:

$$\begin{CD}
0 @>>> \prod_{i > 0}\mathbb{Z} @>{f(e_{ij})=p^jf(e_i)-f(e_{i-j})}>> \prod_{i\ge j>0} \mathbb{Z}\\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
0 @>>> \prod_{i \ge 0}\mathbb{Z} @>{f(e_{ij})=p^jf(e_i)-f(e_{i-j})}>> \prod_{i\ge j>0} \mathbb{Z} \\
@VVV @VVV @VVV \\
\mathbb{Z} @>\text{id}>> \mathbb{Z} @>0>>0
\end{CD}
$$

To know how $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow \mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty},\mathbb{Z})$, we take an $a\in\mathbb{Z}$, which can be induced by $(a,0,0,...)$. This is mapped to $f(e_{ii})=a,f(e_{ij})=0,i\ne j$.

If we can prove $1$ in $\mathrm{Hom}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$, mapped into $\mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}],\mathbb{Z})$ induce the same extension $0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow E\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}\rightarrow 0$, then we are done.

We directly pull back and push out to see, the former is $(\oplus_{i\ge0}\mathbb{Z})/I$, with $I$ generated by $(1,-p,0,0,...), (1,0,-p^2,0,...),(1,0,0,-p^3,...),...$, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]$ by sending $e_i$ to $1/p^i$; the latter is $(q,p)$ with $q-p=n\in\mathbb{Z},q\in\mathbb{Q},p\in\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}$, isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]$ by sending $(q,p)$ to $q$. It is not hard to verify the morphisms in the both extensions are the obvious ones, making them equivalent.

Taking it back, we have $\mathrm{Ext}(\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}],\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: There's one thing I cannot get, why can $P$ be the localization of $Z$ at $(p)$?, I mean $P = \left\{ \frac{m}{p^e} \middle| m, e\in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$, whereas $\mathbb{Z}_{(p)} = \left\{ \frac{m}{n} \middle| m, n \in P \wedge n \ \not\vdots \ p \right\}$. How can they be the same? :( Am I missing something here? :(

Comment: @user49685, you are right. I edited.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but I have one question left, we know that there are cases where $A \cong B \subset Z$ are congruent submodules of some module $Z$, then it's NOT always true that $Z / A \cong Z / B$. For example, take $\mathbb{Z} \cong 3\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}-$module, but of course $\mathbb{Z} / \mathbb{Z} \not \cong \mathbb{Z}/(3\mathbb{Z})$. And you are using the fact that $A \cong B$, and $A \supset C \cong D \subset B$, then $A / C \cong B/D$. I don't think this is correct. :(

Comment: @user49685, thank you very much! I've updated to clarify that. But as my approach gets rather cumbersome, I seriously doubt that I am missing some insight.

Comment: Moreover I don't know what are the extensions corresponding to other integers (and even $p$-adic integers) **explicitly**, though this does not affect the proof. I hope someone can clarify this.

Comment: I'm so sorry if you feel like I'm bordering you so much. :(((((( But for some reason, I cannot see why $\mbox{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty; \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ is exactly the $p-$adic integers. Ok, I agree that if we can find $f(1)$; $f\left( \frac{1}{p} \right)$; ... in such a way that $p.f\left( \frac{1}{p^{k+1}} \right)$ = $p.f\left( \frac{1}{p^{k}} \right)$ then $f$ is totally defined. But how can that be related to $\mathbb{Z}_p$? :((((

Comment: The only connection that I can see is, say I've found $f(1)$, then there are actually $p$ ways that I can define $f\left( \frac{1}{p} \right)$. Say, if $f(1) = \overline{\frac{m}{n}}$, then $f\left( \frac{1}{p} \right) \in \left\{ \overline{\frac{m}{np}}; \overline{\frac{m + n}{np}}; ...; \overline{\frac{m+(p-1)n}{np}} \right\}$. And for each choice of $f\left( \frac{1}{p} \right)$, there will be another $p$ choices for $f\left( \frac{1}{p^2} \right)$; ... But the problem is that, there are uncountably many ways that I can define $f(1)$. How can this be translated into $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @user49685, shouldn't $f(1)$ be $0$ since $1=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}\cong\mathbb{Z}[\frac{1}{p}]/\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Yay, thanks a lot, I think I get it now. :*

Comment: @dentisDark: Why don't you use the injective resolution of Z in the first place? See also my answer.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, you are right. I was not familiar of these at the beginning and I used this as my exercise. So it developed along an unpredictable direction. Indeed, the quick solution is already inherent in the 18-hour-ago comment above.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the definition of $\mathrm{Ext}$! $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ is an injective resolution. It follows that $\mathrm{Ext}^1(P,\mathbb{Z})$ is the cokernel of $\mathrm{hom}(P,\mathbb{Q}) \to \mathrm{hom}(P,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$. For $\phi \in \mathrm{hom}(P,\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ we have $(\phi - \mathrm{pr} \circ q)(1)=\phi(1) - \mathrm{pr}(q)=0$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ resp. $q : P \to \mathbb{Q}$. Therefore

$\mathrm{Ext}^1(P,\mathbb{Z}) = \hom(P/\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})/\mathbb{Z}=\mathrm{End}(\mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty})/\mathbb{Z} = \mathbb{Z}_p/\mathbb{Z}$.

Explicitly, if $\gamma : \mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}$ is an endomorphism, the corresponding extension $0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to E \to P \to 0$ is given by $E=\{(a,b) : b \in P, a \in \mathbb{Z}/p^{\infty}, b \bmod \mathbb{Z} = \gamma(a)\}$.

Similarily one proves that $\mathrm{Ext}^1(\mathbb{Q},\mathbb{Z})=\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your help. There's one thing that I don't think I fully get it. I can see that there's no monomorphism in $\mbox{Hom}(P; \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$, but I just don't see how can we go from here, to infer that all morphisms in $\mbox{Hom}(P; \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ can be factored through $P/ \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I've corrected it.

Comment: The extension isn't quite right: I think it should be $b\in \mathbb{Q}$ and $a\in P$ satisfying $b$ mod $\mathbb{Z} =\gamma(\rho(a))$ for $\rho\colon P\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$ canonical.